# AX=0 for any column vector X and A is a square matrix, A must be zero matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a square matrix and $A=A^T$, suppose that $AX=0$ for any column vector $X$, how to prove that $A$ must be a zero matrix?

Comment: Hint: if $e_1$ is the column vector $\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0}$, what is $Ae_1$?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the condition that $A = A^T$. If $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a square matrix such that $AX = 0$ for all $X \in \mathbb{F}^n$ then $Ae_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$ which must be zero and so $A = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $A:\mathbb R^n→\mathbb R^n$, $AX=0$ for all $X\in \mathbb R^n$ implies $dim(E_0)=n$, where $E_0$ is eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue $0$. Hence the result.